# Duplicate the last row of each group in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have two tables, the first is the term structure of a loan and the second is the interest of a loan. After x years, the loan is moved onto a fixed interest rate structure (it is the opposite in the real world but this is what I am working with for now). My merging table does not always have the same number of rows and so, I am left with a blank number of rows towards the end of each entry.

Table 1 (left table):

```
period Cash flow 
1      400
2      400
3      400
4      400
...   ....
```

Table 2 (right table):

```
period interest rate
1      0.05
2      0.10
```

I am looking to extend the last row (by-entry) of my right table by the length of the left table (by entry)

Table 2 (new right table):

```
period interest rate
1      0.05
2      0.1
3      0.1
4      0.1
```

I have tried to adapt the below code to only use the last line (reference to question given at the end) but I am getting an error message.

The original code is

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['RoomNights'])]
```

The adaptation is attemping to change loc to iloc and selecting the last row to be duplicated by new_len times

```
len(left_table)
len(right_table)
if len(right_table) < len(left_table) + 4:
    new_len = len(left_table) + 4

right_table = right_table.iloc[right_table[-1,:].index.repeat(new_len)]
```

The error message is

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
   period  Cash flow  interest rate
0       1        400           0.05
1       2        400           0.10
2       3        400           0.10
3       4        400           0.10
```